# Confusion over the Universality Property of Coproducts

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

From *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]
[image]

**Question:** Wouldn't universality imply the existence of TWO $h$ -- say $(h_1,h_2)$ -- s.t. $h_1 \circ i = f$ and $h_2 \circ j = g$?

That is, if $u = (i,j): (a,b) \rightarrow (c,c)$, then shouldn't universality imply that for any $n = (f,g): (a,b) \rightarrow (d,d)$, we have that there exists a unique $(h_1, h_2) : (c,c) \rightarrow (d,d)$ with $h_1 \circ i = f$ and $h_2 \circ j = g$? What reason is there to think that $h_1 = h_2$?

Or, if I am right, is Mac Lane just saying that the universality of the codproduct is distinct from the usual notion of universality used elsewhere in category theory?

Comment: I don't know how McLane defined universal properties in general (if he did) but it makes sense that $h_1=h_2$, since we're looking at arrows from $(a,b)$ not to $C\times C$ but to the diagonal functor $\Delta$, and in this setup, an arrow $(c,c) \to (d,d)$ is the $\Delta(f)$ of some $f: c\to d$.

Comment: @Max: Yeah -- this answers the question.